# openERP: Changing "Create" button behavior for Search: Products

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to inherit and add/remove some fields from the default New Product page in openERP. I'd like to change the behavior of the default "Create" button in the Search Products view to send users to the *new* modified Products page, but I can't seem to change it. I've tried XPath, position="replace", and a few other things, but nothing seems to work. How do I grab it? Just use XPath and replace it with another button?

How do I change the results of clicking on that button?

Thanks,

Comment: Please add some more information. Add your codes too

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying the remove the create button shown in the tree view. To remove it there is an openerp module called `web-remove-quick-create`. Its in the [openerp apps](http://apps.openerp.com/addon/8222?filter=%7B%22order_by%22%3a%20%22click_counter%20desc%22,%20%22text_search%22%3a%20%22web%20remove%22%7D&page=0). Please use this. Otherwise try to modify the jc and css files.
Thank you

Comment: That's not in standard addons, so it ought to be a community module. Could you provide a link?

Comment: @DReispt: I have modified my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Jeff,

You can not remove the create button by uisng XPath, position="replace". The Create Button is part of the From view Template which you can find in the web addons part formview js file. and qweb xml template, and You can modify it web with some hard code but that will affect all view as that create button is the Generic/ Common Template to all Views.
So Even if you try CSS and JS stuff I do not suggest.

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

You don't describe what you want to achieve, but a possible solution coudl be:

- Grant your users read-only access to the Product model,  let them
- Create new products through a wizard, opened through a Client Action.

Comment: in a standard install of openERP there is a default page that comes up when you click on "New Products". That same button show up in several menus, but let's limit the discussion to the one under Sales -> Producs -> Products.

Comment: When you click on the Sales -> Producs -> Products button you get a search page. On that search page is a "Create" button that allows you to create a new Product.

Comment: I'd like to change the behvior of that button to send the browser to a custom page. That page is based off the New Products page, but has some fileds removed, and some other fields added.

Comment: It looks like it's not possible to do this, at least not in a relatively easy way, so I'm going to take a different strategy to get what I want.

Comment: @DReispt: giving read only access to product model make it impossible for the user to create it from any means

Comment: Just to be clear, I wasn't trying to block people from creating a new product -- I wanted to have a modified "Create Product" page show up when they click on one particular button.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to modify product form view and remove some of the unnecessary fields  for your application.

you just need to create inherited views for the fields you need to remove from the form view.
for 6.1
to remove the weight field in product form view

1. activate the developer mode by clicking information button next to the exit button on top right and click to the activate developer mode text.
2. open the product form you would like to modify
3. select manage views from developer drop down menu
4. click edit
5. select the field you would like to remove
6. click on inherited view button to create an inherited view and confirm the dialogue go to views from  settings > Customization > User interface > views
7. find the inherited view you just created by writing name or object and checking the few results.
8. the inherited view is like

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<field name='weight' position='after'> </field>
```

- to remove the weight field just change the position property with replace

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<field name='weight' position='replace'> </field>
```

save the inherited view, its done. you can also achieve this by just adding invisible to the filed property like

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<field name='weight' position='replace'><field name='weight' invisible='1'?></field>
```

if there are more than one inherited views referring to the same field you may need to increase or decrease the sequence value of the inherited view to change the order of inherited view to get the necessary behavior.